# How do I find the MAC Address of my Android phone or tablet?

Tags: android, tablet

how to find MAC address(physical address) of android phone .any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 7):

**Manually**

Settings > About Phone > Status > Wi-Fi Mac address

**Programmatically**

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

*YourActivity*

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String mac = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

For future reference, if this wasn't meant to be done in code, this question would be better suited for https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: bunch of thanxx @Andrew Brooke

Comment: This WON'T work on Android 6.0 and above.